# botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials in jenkins

Tags: python, linux, jenkins

I have configured the awscli in my linux server. I have set the credential file. Jenkins is also installed in it.
I have a python code for placing a file from the linux server to AWS s3 bucket.
When I run the script in the linux server it works fine. I get the correct output.

But when I run the same script for a job in jenkins execute shell, it throws the following error:

```
 "File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 312, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 588, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 141, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 166, in _send_request
    request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 150, in create_request
    operation_name=operation_model.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 227, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 210, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 90, in handler
    return self.sign(operation_name, request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 154, in sign
    auth.add_auth(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 408, in add_auth
    super(S3SigV4Auth, self).add_auth(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 340, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE"
```

Any solution????

Comment: Monish, did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes I found the solution

Comment: When We run the python code  through Jenkins, The code checks for the aws credentials file in the Jenkins home directory(eg:  var/lib/Jenkins) under which Jenkins workspace folder and other build  folder are present . So we have to configure aws credentials in the Jenkins directory . Then the python code when executed by Jenkins , it will look for credential in the Jenkins folder (eg: var/lib/Jenkins/.aws) and authenticates the credentials